# background service killed due to excessive cpu usage

Tags: android

I am using android P device. my app is trying to broadcast screen to remote app in the background. it works but after some time, system will kill it:

```
I am_kill : [0,14943,com.xxx.xxx,700,excessive cpu 90610 during 300092 dur=158930 limit=25]
```

I do not want it to be a foreground service to show a notification. any solution to keep it always running?

Comment: Background services [will be stopped after one minute on Android 8.0+](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services).